# Code that expects a block - LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to execute this bit of code :

```
def excel(xlsx_package)
  yield Excel::DSL.new(xlsx_package)
end
```

But when I do :

```
pkg = Axlsx::Package.new
excel(pkg)
```

I get this error :

```
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
from /Users/gandalf/reporter/app/helpers/excel_helper.rb:3:in `excel'
```

How am I supposed to execute the `excel` method? What am I not passing to it now?

Comment: you might just be confusing `yield` with `return`. `yield` will pass the given arguments to a block so the block is required. `return` will return this object (and is not required unless you need to return early).  You could write it like this `excel_dsl = Excel::DSL.new(xlsx_package); block_given? ? yield(excel_dsl) : excel_dsl`. this way if a block is passed it will yield the dsl otherwise it will just return it.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` is used with block given. Example:

```
pkg = Axlsx::Package.new
excel(pkg) do
#some code here
end
```

But I don't know, what you are trying to archive and I am not sure that you need block here.